# GroupBy with latest element and updates instead of key and updates

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I got an Observable, I want to group them modulo 10. I want to make the result to be an hot observable and that when a new subscriber subscribes he got all of the GroupedObservable being played before but instead of getting the Key, I want the latest value. I want the updates as well, skipping the latest value.

In this example, to make it simpler, we will only work with modulo result equals 5. But I want my solution working for everything.

Example:

### --------15-----25---------...

Let's add on the previous example some points in time where we will subscribe:

### ---S1-----15--S2---25-----S3----...

The expected results are:

- S1 to receive Latest: 15, Updates: an observable starting with 25 and updates %10 ==5 that will arrive later.
  Explanation: S1 will be notified after the 15 arrives, 15 is the latest element so I want it straight away. The second argument will be an observable that will produce later 25 and the %10 == 5 elements  in the future.
- S2 to receive Latest: 15, Updates: an observable starting with 25 and updates %10 ==5 that will arrive later.
  Explanation: S2 will be notified on subscription, 15 is the latest element so I want it straight away. The second argument will be an observable that will produce later 25 and the %10 == 5 elements in the future.
- S3 to receive Latest: 25, Updates: an observable with updates %10 ==5 that will arrive later.
  Explanation: S3 will be notified on subscription, 25 is the latest element so I want it straight away. The second argument will be an observable that will produce the %10 == 5 elements in the future.

Here are some resolution tries:

The code below use Tuple and NUnit.

### First attempt

```
[Test]
public void WhenWeGroupByReplaying1()
{
    var subject = new Subject<uint>();

    var observable = subject.GroupBy(t => t%10)
        .Select(t =>
        {
            var connectableObservable = t.Replay(1);
            connectableObservable.Connect();
            return (key: t.Key, updates: connectableObservable);
        }).Replay();

    observable.Connect();

    // I will block on the First of the lambda below
    var getLastAndUpdates = observable
        .Select(t => (first: t.updates.First(),updates: t.updates.Skip(1)));

    getLastAndUpdates.Subscribe(t =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[1] - FIRST: {t.first}");
        t.updates.Subscribe(t2 => Console.WriteLine($"[1] - UPDATE: {t2}"));
    });

    subject.OnNext(15);

    getLastAndUpdates.Subscribe(t =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[2] - FIRST: {t.first}");
        t.updates.Subscribe(t2 => Console.WriteLine($"[2] - UPDATE: {t2}"));
    });

    subject.OnNext(25);

    getLastAndUpdates.Subscribe(t =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[3] - FIRST: {t.first}");
        t.updates.Subscribe(t2 => Console.WriteLine($"[3] - UPDATE: {t2}"));
    });
}
```

This solution will be blocking as shown in comment.

### Second attempt

```
[Test]
public void WhenWeGroupByReplaying2()
{
    var subject = new Subject<uint>();

    var observable = subject.GroupBy(t => t, t => t, new ModuloEqualityComparer())
        .Select(t =>
        {
            var connectableObservable = t.Publish(t.Key);
            connectableObservable.Connect();
            return (key: t.Key, updates: connectableObservable);
        }).Replay();

    observable.Connect();

    var getLastAndUpdates = observable
        .Select(t => (first: t.updates.First(),updates: t.updates.Skip(1)));

    getLastAndUpdates.Subscribe(t =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[1] - FIRST: {t.first}");
        t.updates.Subscribe(t2 => Console.WriteLine($"[1] - UPDATE: {t2}"));
    });

    subject.OnNext(15);

    getLastAndUpdates.Subscribe(t =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[2] - FIRST: {t.first}");
        t.updates.Subscribe(t2 => Console.WriteLine($"[2] - UPDATE: {t2}"));
    });

    subject.OnNext(25);

    getLastAndUpdates.Subscribe(t =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[3] - FIRST: {t.first}");
        t.updates.Subscribe(t2 => Console.WriteLine($"[3] - UPDATE: {t2}"));
    });
}

private class ModuloEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<uint>
{
    public bool Equals(uint x, uint y)
    {
        return x % 10 == y % 10;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(uint obj)
    {
        return (obj % 10).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
[1] - FIRST: 15
[1] - UPDATE: 15
[2] - FIRST: 15
[1] - UPDATE: 25
[2] - UPDATE: 25
[3] - FIRST: 25
```

Expected result: (exact order doesn't mater)

```
[1] - FIRST: 15
[2] - FIRST: 15
[1] - UPDATE: 25
[2] - UPDATE: 25
[3] - FIRST: 25
```

### Third attempt

```
[Test]
public void WhenWeGroupByReplaying3()
{
    var subject = new Subject<uint>();

    var observable = subject.GroupBy(t => (key: t%10, value:t), t => t, new ModuloEqualityComparer2())
        .Select(t =>
        {
            var connectableObservable = t.Publish(t.Key.Item2);
            connectableObservable.Connect();
            return (key: t.Key, updates: connectableObservable);
        }).Replay();

    observable.Connect();

    var getLastAndUpdates = observable
        .Select(t => (first: t.updates.First(),updates: t.updates.Skip(1)));

    getLastAndUpdates.Subscribe(t =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[1] - FIRST: {t.first}");
        t.updates.Subscribe(t2 => Console.WriteLine($"[1] - UPDATE: {t2}"));
    });

    subject.OnNext(15);

    getLastAndUpdates.Subscribe(t =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[2] - FIRST: {t.first}");
        t.updates.Subscribe(t2 => Console.WriteLine($"[2] - UPDATE: {t2}"));
    });

    subject.OnNext(25);

    getLastAndUpdates.Subscribe(t =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[3] - FIRST: {t.first}");
        t.updates.Subscribe(t2 => Console.WriteLine($"[3] - UPDATE: {t2}"));
    });
}

private class ModuloEqualityComparer2 : IEqualityComparer<(uint,uint)>
{
    private readonly ModuloEqualityComparer _moduloEqualityComparer = new ModuloEqualityComparer();
    public bool Equals((uint, uint) x, (uint, uint) y)
    {
        return _moduloEqualityComparer.Equals(x.Item1, y.Item1);
    }


    public int GetHashCode((uint, uint) obj)
    {
        return _moduloEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(obj.Item1);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
[1] - FIRST: 15
[1] - UPDATE: 15
[2] - FIRST: 15
[1] - UPDATE: 25
[2] - UPDATE: 25
[3] - FIRST: 25
```

Expected result: (exact order doesn't mater)

```
[1] - FIRST: 15
[2] - FIRST: 15
[1] - UPDATE: 25
[2] - UPDATE: 25
[3] - FIRST: 25
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, but hopefully this will help you:

There's a couple things wrong with your code:

1. `.First()` is obsolete for a reason. You shouldn't be using blocking code with Rx
2. `.Replay()` requires a dummy subscription to work correctly. I'm not sure if that's what was plaguing your code or not, but to achieve your aims, you want that.
3. Nested subscriptions are generally a bad idea. I have replaced the nested subscriptions with a `.Merge()`.

If this doesn't solve your problem, I suggest amending your question to describe what you're trying to accomplish by using Rx. This smells a bit like an [XY situation](http://xyproblem.info/).

Here's the code:

```
var subject = new Subject<uint>();

var observable = subject.GroupBy(t => t % 10)
    .Select(t => t.Replay(1).RefCount()).Replay().RefCount();

// dummy subscriptions required for Replay to work correctly.
var dummySub = observable.Merge().Subscribe();

observable
    .Select(o => o.Select((t, index) => (t.Key, t.num, index)))
    .Merge()
    .Subscribe(t =>
    {
        if (t.index == 0)
            Console.WriteLine($"[1] - FIRST: {t.num}");
        else
            Console.WriteLine($"[1] - UPDATE: {t.num}");
    });

subject.OnNext(15);

observable
    .Select(o => o.Select((t, index) => (t.Key, t.num, index)))
    .Merge()
    .Subscribe(t =>
    {
        if (t.index == 0)
            Console.WriteLine($"[1] - FIRST: {t.num}");
        else
            Console.WriteLine($"[1] - UPDATE: {t.num}");
    });

subject.OnNext(25);

observable
    .Select(o => o.Select((t, index) => (t.Key, t.num, index)))
    .Merge()
    .Subscribe(t =>
    {
        if (t.index == 0)
            Console.WriteLine($"[1] - FIRST: {t.num}");
        else
            Console.WriteLine($"[1] - UPDATE: {t.num}");
    });
```